# Get an array of category details with category name in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have an URL like this https://example.com/parent-category/child-category/

With the function `single_cat_title()`
`$category = single_cat_title('', false);` I am getting the name of the active category. Now, how can I get the details of the category with the name I am getting in the `$category` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
print_r( $queried_object ); ?>
```